# how to append text adverisement to MMS message body

Tags: android, mms

I am developing an android app,in that i am implementing MMS functionality by using intents.

The following is my code.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, 
                    Uri.parse("mms://")); 
                    sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
                    String url = "file://sdcard//tmpPhoto.jpg"; 
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
                        sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.everytize", "Continue");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "MMS:"));
```

when i click on MMS button its invoking the built in MMS app.But i want to append text advertisement(from server) to the body of the message while sending.by using Httpget method ,i am calling server and getting the advertisement.Now i want to append this advertisement to the body of text message.how to do.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append text to the sms/mms body, all you need to do is:

```
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse("mms://"));
messageIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");
```